# AWS Cloudwatch unable to retrieve Billing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I was setting up the cloudwatch to monitor the Billing information. However, after the preference option is enabled, no data is retrieved and displayed on CloudWatch.

#### What has been done:

1. the "Receive Billing Alerts" option is enabled in Billing Preference.
2. change endpoint to "US East N.Virginia" for cloudwatch to check metrics.

#### Result:

no data

#### Questions:

1. the "Receive Billing Alerts" option is showing a little bit grey out and "weaken" when comparing with other options in the same page. I am not sure if it is normal or something broken?
2. the "Receive Billing Alerts" option cannot be unticked. nothing is happened no matter how many times I clicked on the option;
3. 0 is displayed in the Alarm Preview when I was trying create alarm. I believe that is because no data was retrieved.

It is quite frustrated especially when you expected that should be very simple task. But, it is just not working! It would be very appreciated if anyone could shed the light for me.

Answer (score 2):

the problem magically resolved itself after one night sleep. I guess that the cloudwatch only retrieve Billing data once per day and I just need to wait. However, since there is nowhere mentioned about that in AWS docunmentation, I assume that should be more frequently. Anyway, problem solved.